# MSBuild won't recognize C# 6 syntax in one of my projects

Tags: .net, msbuild

I'm getting errors about C# 6 syntax elements when building the solution using msbuild; however, everything compiles perfectly from the VS. Setting the target C# version to 6 explicitly results in a build error: "Invalid option '6' for /langversion; must be ISO-1, ISO-2, 3, 4, 5 or Default"
The version reported by msbuild is:

> ...>msbuild /version         Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 4.6.1038.0                  [Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.42000]            Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> 4.6.1038.0

i.e. the latest one, as far as I understand. 
Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: You are using the wrong MSBuild.exe version.  The one in the C:\Windows\Microsoft.net directory is legacy and retained only to avoid breaking custom build servers.  The proper one is C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe.  It is version 14.0.25123.0, give or take.

Comment: @Hans Passant, that's exactly the version that I've added to the path variable.

Comment: Modifying PATH is a good way to have two problems.  Type `where msbuild.exe` at the commend prompt, first one that's listed is used.

Comment: @Hans Passant, aha there are 2 ones there. This explains the problem.